# How google AdSense works?

Tags: html, google-ads-api, adsense

I am getting unsupported language error from google AdSense while applying for the monetization program. My website lists images with unsupported language text on it. Does google check that level or how exactly does it check the website primary language? And also can I have some pages with supported language with link to unsupported language page?